# Amazon EC2 Regions and Zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My experiment requires a server at specific geographic location different from my country. Can anyone clarify to me whether renting an amzon EC2 instance at that zone (country) means that the EC2 is physically running in that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All AWS resources (including Amazon EC2 instances) are launched in a specified **region**. Each region consists of multiple **data centers**. The data centers are located in the physical location indicated by the name of the region, such as Sydney, Singapore and Canada (Central).

So, yes, the EC2 instance is physically running in that location.

A list of AWS Regions is available at: [Global Cloud Infrastructure | Regions & Availability Zones | AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/)